# Force attribute usage in subclass of abstract superclass

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, custom-attributes

How can I force a subclass to implement certain Attributes of its superclass? The reason is that I want to use Attributes for general information about the class, e.g. "DisplayName", "Description" or "Capabilities".

So I thought I might implement them in a superclass and force the subclasses to implement the attributes.

Is there something like an `abstract` attribute like for methods?

```
[abstract DeclareMe]
public abstract class InheritMe {
    public abstract void DeclareMe();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927230/force-attribute-declaration-in-derived-classes

Comment: The answer to that question explains how to inherit already declared attributes to subclasses, this is not the question here.

Comment: If you already mark fields and methods in abstract class all child with get it by default you don't need to force anything

Comment: But I'm talking about attributes, not fields or methods.

Comment: The answers to the question linked by @Anand are relavent though. You can't force attribute usage at compile time, therefore there can be no such thing as an `abstract` attribute. You do get a kind of virtuality by using an attribute on the base class but, that is not what you are asking.

Comment: I am saying marking them like this e.g.  [DisplayName("Identity")] public int id { get; set; } in your abstract class

Comment: So what are the possible workarounds for what I want to do? I don't think creating a bunch of abstract `getMetadata()` methods is the best practice for this task?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As your class must be run sooner or later, you can add checking mechanism to your base class to verify the existance of certain attributes in your sub classes.

Here's some sample code for you.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new SubA();
        var b = new SubB();
    }
}

class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        Type t = GetType();
        if (t.IsDefined(typeof(SerializableAttribute), false) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bad implementation");
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("good implementation");
    }
}

[Serializable]
class SubA : BaseClass
{ }

class SubB : BaseClass
{ }
```

The last word, don't be too wary of yourself. Once I was doing my design, I always thought I might call two methods in a wrong order or forget to do something, then I turned a simple design into a complicated one to prevent my possible mistakes. Later I threw away the guards, just throwing Exceptions and the code used to detect unexpected situations were surrounded by `#if DEBUG`.

Comment: Principle of Life: Code in #if debug will _never_ be hit on the developer machine, but the checked problem _will_ occur on the customer's machine

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answers from that other thread:

You could use [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and implement a custom rule that checks if your attributes are present.