# How to make static class description that is required for subclasses?

Tags: c#

EDIT: I am not necessarily asking for a property. If there's a way to make a required attribute, then that's fine too.

I can't do `abstract static` in C#, so how can I make a static property `Description` of a type and require it in sub types?

```
public abstract class TypeA
{
    public /*required*/ static String Description {get;}
}

public class TypeB : TypeA
{
    //description not implemented, compile error
}
```

Note that I am aware this can be done when it's not static, but I feel a description of the type is much more correct when it's static. E.g. `TypeB.Description` is very clear, `instance.Description` is misleading at best.

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11409439/1094268) suggesting to check for an attribute in constructor is the best I've come across so far, but still I'd like a restriction that's compile-time.

Comment: Not sure to understand : you would have a static inherited property, and would hope that TypeB.Description could be different than TypeC.Description, for example ??? Not really coherent with static, no ?

Comment: You can't do this with static classes and members that's not how they work. You might actually find the singleton pattern more useful here, you can keep your inheritance that way.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus not inherited, but required. So, not implemented in the base class, but the base class could force the subclasses to imlepement it.

Comment: @Lloyd The classes have other uses too, so I can't really use singleton

Comment: @DavidS. Ok. Then dcastro's answer explains well why it's not possible, and Ian's one is a good alternative. You could also go for an abstract property with a protected setter (or no setter), but... I guess you're aware of this.

Comment: static member means that **the type has this member** not an instance. So it won't inherit never.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance and static members don't mix.

You cannot inherit static members. If a base class and a derived class happen to each have a member with the same signature, these members are in no way related to each other.

This means you can't force a subclass to "implement a static member". This is also the reason why interfaces don't have static members.

Comment: I understand. I wish there was a way to require Attributes, then. So I could force description attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe what you're trying to achieve is possible I'm afraid, but something that might work which I've used in a similar way before is using class attributes which may give you your desired result:

```
[Description("This is a Type B")]
public class TypeB : TypeA
{

}
```

Then you'll be able to access this description from the Type instead of an instance. You may also be able to use the [AttributeUsageAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to then automatically inherit from a base class. You may even be able to define a special attribute that throws an Exception or something similar if used - this would give you a runtime error obviously if it's not been set.

Comment: Yes this will be roughly the same solution as the one I linked to, with runtime check for the attribute. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to inherit static member cuz it is owned by type. You can inherit only non-static types with everything is static like follows:

```
    public abstract class TypeA
    {
        public class Description
        {
            public static String Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
    public class TypeB : TypeA
    {
        public string AccessToStaticMember { get; private set; }
        public TypeB()
        {
            AccessToStaticMember = Description.Name;
        }
    }
```